# My selenium code is not working and giving element not interactable error

Tags: python, selenium

I've tried everything from waits to xpath but it's not working somehow, I want to enter some value in input field on the page with id, but its not becoming interactable, any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://voip.ms/login")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,   '//input[@id="username"]')))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to click an input field, instead you have to `send_keys()` the username directly. However, it appears that there are two input fields with `id="username"` and you are picking the first one which isn't the one you want.

A work around for that would be to get both of them by using `driver.get_elements_by_xpath()` then choose the 2nd one (this is not the best practice, instead you should find a unique identifier for the input field) here is an example of getting both of them and choosing the 2nd one:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://voip.ms/login")
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@id="username"]')[1]
element.send_keys('your username')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair since last 6 hours and almost on the verge of break down. you're the savior.